# How long to steam tofu (extra firm) without predrying or what is cooked temperature?

Tags: tofu

I understand meats have recommended cooking temperatures to tell when they are done, but the extra firm tofu I buy says to fry it for like 8-10 minutes or something. I want to steam this tofu and was wondering if I should be doing it for X time or aiming for a certain internal temperature like meat. How can I determine when the tofu is done.

I am also very lazy so I don't thoroughly dry or press the tofu before cooking.

I'm just looking to cook the tofu to make it easy/safe tp eat, no particular culinary texture/flavor goals.

Comment: It's good to be lazy.  Drying/pressing tofu is largely a waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

Is your aim to just "cook" the tofu or are you trying achieve a particular texture or flavor?

If the concern is safety or "rawness" of some sort, tofu is cooked and perfectly edible as-is. Really, just warming it up (or not at all!) to the temperature you want should be fine.

The instruction for frying has a set time because it aims to significantly change the flavor/texture of the tofu. If your aim is to change the tofu somehow, I don't expect steaming to do much, as the process of making tofu itself already involves steaming (or boiling, depending on exact method) the soybeans.

Comment: I'm just looking to cook the tofu to make it easy/safe to eat, no particular culinary texture/flavor goals, updating question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Steaming or boiling or microwaving until 100c boiling point will get the tofu to release excess water and therefore hold onto any seasonings added after.

A good step before frying if no flour/starch coat is used to aid a nice crust.

From microwave, you can hear and see tofu sizzle when hot. By boiling, depending on thickness, 2 - 10min.
Steaming harder to judge temp without laser.

Simply strain in colander and maybe a firm pat dry.

Watch soy sauce etc soak in without typical puddle forming from salty condiments added to straight-from-fridge tofu